# What to use instead of Concat in string lists in C#

Tags: c#, string, list, concatenation, directory-listing

I have these lists of strings

```
List<string> files = new List<string>
                    (System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat
                    (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "*.*"),
                    System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "*.pdf")));
```

I want to refactor code and I want to use something more efficient or faster than concat.How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: "*more efficient or faster*" - The majority of time will not be spent in `Concat`, it will be spent enumerating the files.. Additionally, you could possibly use  a single search pattern instead of 2 calls to `GetFiles`

Comment: You get all files and next all pdf, from the same folder, hence the last is useless since the first got them... So no need to concat and you can use ToList Linq extension method on GetFiles.

Comment: There is also `list.AddRange()`, but I would expect minor, if any difference.

Comment: @OlivierRogier: Maybe he wants all pdfs twice in the list?

Comment: @SomeBody Indeed... but... why ?

Comment: how can I use ToList here?

Comment: _"how can I use ToList here"_ : `var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "*.*").ToList()`

Comment: `ToList` is not going to help... However `"*.pdf"` is a subset of `"*.*"` You are saying to someone "*Give me a list of all cars, then give me a list of all red cars, then join the lists together (somehow)*" you are making them run around twice for no reason and wondering why its taking a long time

Comment: If ToList doesn't work then what should I do then to create the list of files

Comment: It will work, but it will have no appreciable difference. Just call `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "*.*")` once and be done with it, it will give you pfs

Comment: Hang on, lets take a step-back.... What are you trying to do? Get a list of *pdfs* ?

Comment: yes I want to get the list of everything.this wasn't my code all I'm trying to do is refactor it

Answer (score 1):

To get a `List<string>` of all files, you can write:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*").ToList();
```

This will includes all PDF.

If you don't need a `List<>` for a special purpose, you can directly manipulate the resulting string array of GetFiles:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*");
```

Or simply:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*");
```

This will avoid the memory and time needed to do the conversion to a generic list of strings.

You can access items and loop foreach the same with an array or a list as they implement IEnumerable and have indexer.

A list is only useful if you need to easily manipulate items such as adding and removing, or want an OOP object for any reason.

Also as suggested by @mjwills you can use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`: the first time you will parse the list you don't need to wait for the full populating and there will be no eventual lag in case of lots of files:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*");

foreach (var filePath in files) ...
```

But it will re-scan the system file every time you perform a parsing and this is useful only if one parsing is made or if realtime parsing is needed.

Comment: I'd suggest `EnumerateFiles`.